# Create a variable file path

Tags: python, bash

I have two scripts that I'd like to run side by side:

1. A python script that downloads an image from google
2. A bash script that processes said image

Both scripts work fine in their own right. The problem I'm having is integrating the two. I want to set it up so that I can have the script run at regular intervals by itself. To do this, I need to be able to pass the file path(s) of my image(s) from my python script into my bash script for processing.

They are two separate scripts. My python script generates a random word and uses that as a search term. It will then download an image from google images and save it to /pictures/$RANDOMWORD.jpg. I need to be able to point my Bash script to /pictures/$RANDOMWORD.jpg to retrieve and process the image.

Comment: Please explain more. Does the Python script run the bash script or are they complete separate? if separate you might run the python script to save the images to a specific location and add a watch (like `inotifywait`) to that folder to run the bash script on changes....

Comment: They are two separate scripts. My python script generates a random word and uses that as a search term. It will then download an image from google images and save it to /pictures/$RANDOMWORD.jpg. I need to be able to point my Bash script to /pictures/$RANDOMWORD.jpg for processing

Comment: You can print the name and read it in bash as `RANDOMWORD=$(python download.py)`

Comment: Alternatively, you can pipe it: `$ python download.py | ./process.sh` and use `read` to read the filename.
Alternatively alternatively, you can print the actual bytestream you downloaded to stdout, the use the bash script to process the file `/dev/stdin`.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to simplify my image grabbing script print the output path using RANDOMWORD=$(python imagegrabber.py).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you could do is create a cronjob to run the python script and have this script always running to monitor that folder. here is an example of an inotifywait:

```
inotifywait -m $TEST_DIR -e create |
    while read path action file; do
        echo "Processing: '$path$file'"
        if [ ${file: -4} == ".jpg" ]
        then
            echo "Processing image..."
#            your code here
        else
            echo "The file does not seem to be an image file... ignoring."
        fi
    done
```

**OR**

if you want to pass the found images to the bash script you actually can 
 call it from python.

You can do this with `os.system(command)` of `os.popen(cmd, mode='r', buffering=-1)`

Here is the [os.popen](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html#os.popen)

**OR**

You can pipe them to each other e.g.

```
python python_script.py | bash_script.sh
```

so that the output of the py will go into the bash script